# Assign large ammount of Models to a Collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, local-storage

I have an array containing ~1200 Objects which I want to assign to a Collection but I always get timed out.

I tried this (not very elegant I admit):

```
_.each(mightyArray, function(mightyArrayItem){
  BigCollection.create(mightyArrayItem);
});
```

This works but is horrible slow :-(

**Edit**

Perhaps I'm on the wrong track. I'm using [backbone-localstorage.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html) instead of some kind of remote DB so it could be that the `localStorage` itself is slowing down everything?

**Edit 2**

I think the problem is the performance of `localStorage.setItem()`. I'll try `indexedDB` now :-/

**Update / Solution**

After I added the data on the index.html it worked for some reason. Maybe a scope issue..

```
<script> 
  BigCollection.allItems = new BigCollection.AllItems();
  BigCollection.allItems.add( BigCollection.allItemsArray ); // Add all the data
</script>
```

Comment: What about `BigCollection.add(mightyArray);` ?

Comment: Yeah. Is it the syncing `create()` x 1200 that's causing the slow down? You might want to create the collection first then do a BATCH `save()` rather than trying to save each model 1 by 1. @nikoshr , why not just `BigCollection.reset(arrayHash)` ?

Comment: @orangewarp equivalent if the collection is empty, but the collection may already have models, so add to be safe.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. :-)

Comment: @nikoshr I tried the `BigCollection.add(mightyArray)` variant but I got a collection with no Models.

Comment: @orangewarp Yep, it's the ammount of `create` calls. I tried it with 200. No prob then. With 400 there was a noticeable slowdown.

Comment: I think we're missing something here. Here's a working example of what I meant http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/VceET/ Do you want to save your models too? If yes, you should follow @orangewarp advice and save all of them in one go.

Comment: @Saschlong Are you defining your `models` property of the collection? `add()` normally takes models as argument but it can take a model hash... only if the collection knows what model it is supposed to represent. Although if you're using `create()` and it works... you must have it defined... Hm. [Collection.models property](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-models)

Comment: @orangewarp `BigCollection.reset(arrayHash)` works in the console but not in the actual code. What am I missing?

Comment: Hm. Not sure I can answer that given the snippet of code you posted. Can you update what you have (code-wise) with a little more context? Any errors?

Comment: @orangewarp I have a file with a huge json variable. When I open the Index-Page of the project the `Collection` / `localStorage` should get populated. But this works only up to a certain ammount of models. Everything is fine until I want to save them. Then it lags. I tried to cycle through in chunks, but somehow I don't get it to work :-/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating 1200 request. You should probably better make your own request that saves data to the server, then make

```
BigCollection.add(mightyArray,{silent: true});
```

Passing silent will avoid all the requests to the server.

Comment: For some reason this works in the console but not if I add it in my JS-File?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your sentence. Could you give some code to explain ?

Comment: When I'm using `add`in the Chrome Developer Tools Console I can use the data in the `BigCollection`. When I do the same in the JS-File where I defined the Collection I get a `BigCollection` with length 0.